# How to use ApplyAction

Tags: manatee.trello

I've been trying to search for information on how use the copyCard trello action, it looks like I should use Card.ApplyAction, but I am not sure if thats the correct way. I have not found how to set the needed data on the action to copy the card.

Is there a method in Manatee.Trello to copy a card or do I just do it all myself? If there is how do you use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy a card, you'll need the destination list.  If you're just trying to put it in the same list, that's `card.List`.

Then you can just add a new card using the existing card as a source:

```
var card = new Card("<card ID>");
var copy = Card.List.Cards.Add(card);
```

Done!

### Edit for completeness

The `ActionTypes` enum serves two purposes:

1. Identify the type of action when you get the list of actions (`card.Actions`) for objects that expose them (boards, lists, cards, etc.)
2. Filter actions that are included in the `Filter()` extension method.

You can find out more on the [Manatee.Trello wiki](https://github.com/gregsdennis/Manatee.Trello/wiki)

### Another edit for more completeness

The `card.ApplyAction()` method is for web hooks.  When a request is received, the content is deserialized as a string and passed to this method.  It is an alternative updating mechanism from the default on-demand polling.

Comment: It looks like I didn't quite answer your question about `ApplyAction()` so I made an edit.